# How can I place a dot before the last three digits in a terminal output

Tags: regex, linux, sed, terminal

What is the best way to place a dot after the last three dots in a terminal output?

I want to get from this: `10902MB/88%`

to this: `10.902MB/88%`

Currently I have this command for that:

```
df -m /dev/sda8 | grep -Eo '[0-9]*  [0-9]*%'| sed 's/  */MB\//g'
```

#### Edit

The output of `df -m /dev/sda8 is

```
Filesystem     1M-blocks  Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda8          90349 74910     10828  88% /
```

I need only the `Available` and `Use%` values.

Comment: What is the output of `df -m /dev/sda8`? Need it so we can attempt on single solution than using multiple `grep`/`sed` combinations

Comment: What is the output of `df -m /dev/sda8` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to get values of "*Available*" and "*Use%*" sections from `df` command output for a certain mounted file system.
Use the following `sed` approach:

```
df -m /dev/sda8 | sed -En 's~.* ([0-9]+)([0-9]{3}) +([0-9]+%).*~\1.\2MB/\3~gp'
```

Comment: It does not print out anything in the terminal, if I copy it exactly as you wrote

Comment: @Jonas, so why haven't you posted the output of `df -m /dev/sda8` ?

Comment: I added it to my answer. I thought this wouldn't be relevant. Sorry

Comment: Working perfectly!

Answer (score 2):

```
echo 10902MB/88% | awk '{gsub(/[0-9][0-9][0-9]MB\//, ".&")} 1'
```

or

```
df -m /dev/sda8 | awk '{gsub(/[0-9][0-9][0-9]MB\//, ".&")} 1'
```

Comment: While the `echo` command works, the second command just prints `df -m /dev/sda8` without the `awk` command following.